# Simple wordpress shortcode function

Tags: php

I have a little piece of code that makes a shortcode in my WordPress theme function file.

This is the code:

```
function myshort_title($atts){
  $title = get_the_title();
  $short_title = wp_trim_words( $title, 2, '' );
  return $short_title;
}

add_shortcode( 'short_title', 'myshort_title' );
```

and I use it like this:

[short_title]

Ok...what I want is the result of that shortcode to be written permanently into my WordPress posts so that when I edit my posts I don't want to see that shortcode, I want to see the result.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking

Comment: so if the tile is: Most Searched on Google the shortcode output is "most searched" but when i disable the plugin in my wordpress post will remain [short_title]...i want the output to be written in my post! so when i disable the plugin i will have in my post "most searched" not [short_title]

Comment: then add the shortcode through functions.php in your theme and not as a plugin

Comment: so you understood what i want? if you really want to help me please do, but don;t give me a solution that will not do what i want it to do!